# Hausdorff property is not homotopy invariant

Tags: general-topology, homotopy-theory

In *Topology: A Categorical Approach* it's stated that the Hausdorff property is topological but not homotopy invariant. The only example that I know of a "naturally occurring" non-Hausdorff space is the line with two origins, and the only thing I can think to do is use the quotient procedure that created it, but I don't think that produces a homotopy equivalence. Is there an elementary example of a homotopy equivalence between a Hausdorff and non-Hausdorff space? Or am I wrong in thinking that the quotient procedure $(x,a) \sim (x,b)$ if $x \neq 0$ does not give a homotopy equivalence?

Comment: small note: *maps* can be homotopic; *spaces* can be homotopy equivalent

Comment: @ElliotG totally right, my mistake

Comment: $[0,1]$ with the indiscrete (trivial) topology is homotopy equivalent to the one-point space.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott ah thank you!

Comment: @perpetuallyconfused: You’re welcome!

Comment: Specifically all maps into any space $X$ with only two open sets is continuous so there is a homotopy $H: X \times I \rightarrow X$ which takes the identity to a constant map.

Comment: @NoelLundström just to make sure I have it clear, since $H:X \times I \to X$ is a map into $X$ with the trivial topology, it's automatically continuous. So to show that $gf \simeq \text{id}_X$ I can pick $H(x,t) = gf(x)$ if $t \in [0,1)$ and $H(x,1)=x$.

Comment: Yes, that's correct! @perpetuallyconfused

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an example of a non-Hausdorff space:

Let $X$ be your favourite nontrivial Hausdorff space. Let $Y=X\times\left\{1,2\right\}$ be the product space of $X$ with the chaotic topological space $\left\{1,2\right\}$, where the only open subsets of $\left\{1,2\right\}$ are $\varnothing$ and $\left\{1,2\right\}$ itself.

More informally, $Y$ consists of two copies of $X$, namely $X_1=X\times\left\{1\right\}$ and $X_2=X\times\left\{2\right\}$. Obviously, $Y$ is not Hausdorff.

But $X$ and $Y$ are homotopy invariant: Take the maps $f\colon X\to Y$ which maps $X$ to the first copy of it inside $Y$: $f(x)=(x,1)$; and let $g\colon Y\to X$ maps whatever element of any copy of $X$ to the same element of $X$: $g(x,i)=x$.

Then $gf=\operatorname{id}_X$, and the function
$$H\colon Y\times[0,1]\to Y,\qquad H((x,i),t)=\begin{cases}(x,1)&\text{ if }t=0\\(x,i)&\text{ if }t>0\end{cases}$$
is a homotopy from $fg$ to $\operatorname{id}_Y$. [The only nontrivial part is continuity of $H$: Note that $H^{-1}(U)=U\times[0,1]$ for all $U\subseteq Y$ open.]